# Display the last saved user ID and Name in labels using c# and winforms

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a windows form application in C# where I saved details like name, `ID` etc into a database. The `ID` is given by the database so the user does not supply any `ID`. I want to add another functionality where once I saved the name and `ID`, I automatically get the most recent saved name and `ID` from the database and display it on `label 1` and `label 2` on the same form. I'm new to C# so any help is greatly appreciated.

This is the code for saving

```
private void btnregister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    cn.Open();

    cmd = new SqlCommand(
      "INSERT INTO register (FirstName, LastName) VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName)", cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtfname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtlname.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("saved");
    cn.Close();
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot Save");
  }
}
```

Comment: Create a stored procedure. either handle return value or output parameter.

Comment: Side note: put your `cn` and `cmd` into `using`. If exception will be thrown you will got an undisposed resource

Comment: You already know the last saved name. Do you have concurrent inserts from different users?

Comment: @Steve no i don't. It's a desktop a standalone desktop app.

Comment: Then your textboxes already have the information about first and last name. Are you searching for something different?

Comment: @Steve since the ID is supplied by the database upon insertion the user has no way of knowing which ID has been assigned to him/her. Hence l want to find out the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your query as to this, assuming your ID field is named `Id` in the table:

```
INSERT INTO register (FirstName, LastName)
output inserted.Id 
VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName)
```

`output inserted.Id` is the query part you are looking for.
Use then `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` to catch the Id value: beware that it will return null if no Ids have been generated.

Your final code would be:

```
private void btnregister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var insertedId = 0;
    try
    {
        cn.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand(
            "INSERT INTO register (FirstName, LastName) output inserted.Id VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName)", cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtfname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtlname.Text);
        var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        try
        {
            insertedId = (int) result;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception("No rows were added");
        }
        MessageBox.Show("saved");
        cn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot Save");
    }
}
```

Comment: This (while correct) doesn't solve the problem to retrieve the last name inserted if there are multiple inserts from different users.

Comment: @k1dev how would l put this in actual code. I keep getting errors with what l'm doing.

Comment: Check the answer

Comment: @Steve I don't think he is asking for a solution to implement in a multi-user application. If he is, I will provide another solution for it.